# Why is express not available outside of the local machine?

Tags: javascript, express, xmlhttprequest

So I have an mysql database running on my server which is accessed using express and node. The problem I am having is that when I call an express endpoint from my browser the connection times out. However, if I `wget ipaddress:3030/matches/` from the server itself the data returns correctly.

Why can I not access the endpoint from my browser?
Thank  you!

This is what my dbconnect.js looks like

```
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    //DB properies..
    host: "localhost",
    user: "admin",
    password: "******",
    socketPath:"/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock",
    database: "conp2"
});

var port = 3030;
connection.connect(function (error) {       //connect to database
    if (!!error){
        console.log(error);
        console.log("Error Connecting to database");
    } else {
        console.log("Connected to port:" + port);
    }
});

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    next();
});

app.get("/matches", function (req,res) {
    res.send("example");
}

app.listen(port);
```

Comment: Make sure you bind to 0.0.0.0 instead of 127.0.0.1

Comment: @meyer9 what would that change? I tried it but I still cant access it